# 2 Dates from the same column in one SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to work out an average between of time between two dates in the same field.

Basically i've got a transaction date and an id for each transaction and a customer id for each transaction.

I need to get the time between the first transaction and the second transaction. I dont mind working out the average between the two in excel but I dont know how to pull two dates from the same field.

transaction.created_at of the first transaction minus transaction.created_at of the second transaction for each and every customer in the database. I can pull the date of a transaction like

```
select
customer.id,
transaction.created_at
count(transaction.id)
from transaction

having count(transaction.id) = 2
```

Thanks

Comment: So is it MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will always be Having count(*) = 2?  If so, I think you could just use min and max, no?

```
/*
create table dbo.Example (tran_id int,created_at datetime,cust_id int)
insert dbo.example values (1,'10/1/2012',900)
insert dbo.example values (2,'10/2/2012',901)
insert dbo.example values (3,'10/18/2012',590)
insert dbo.example values (4,'10/10/2012',676)
insert dbo.example values (5,'10/11/2012',123)
insert dbo.example values (6,'10/17/2012',456)
insert dbo.example values (7,'10/9/2012',901)
insert dbo.example values (8,'10/30/2012',900)
insert dbo.example values (9,'10/4/2012',456)
insert dbo.example values (10,'10/17/2012',676)
*/
select 
cust_id,
max([created_at]) as [Last Date],
min([created_at]) as [First Date],
datediff(hh,min([created_at]) ,max([created_at])) as [Hours diff]
from example
group by cust_id
having count(*) = 2
order by cust_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to retrieve particular customer transactions count:

```
Select
Customer.id,
count(transaction.id)
from transaction
where Customer.id = '10'
```

Here 10 specifies the `customer id` that has been searched by you. You have to pass this `customer id` as parameter in your created SP.

Comment: Yeah, but i'm needing to pull the 2 dates for a large database of people, not individual customer ID's. Effectively i'm requiring 3 columns. 1 with customer_ID, one with date of the first transaction and one for the second transaction date.